# How to write our home address in formal forms

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

If I write the address as below:

**No 21, 15 Alpha St, Babol, Mazandaran, Iran** what does it mean?

1. > There are multiple Alpha Streets and I am living in the 15th brunch.( I think this is correct)

or

2. > There is a single street having the name "15 Alpha".

**Question**:

If (1) is true, what should write if there is only a single street having the name "15 Alpha" and I live in.

---

**Additional Info**:

"21" is the house number.

"15 Alpha" is an important date in Iran History which is considered for the name of a street.

Comment: Apparently, Google Map couldn't find "Alpha St, Babol, Mazandaran, Iran", even though it can take you to "Babol, Mazandaran, Iran" on the map instantly.

Comment: @DamkerngT., Apparently I have right to avoid disclosing my private information. Don't I ?

Comment: Sure! Please don't get me wrong. I just wish you had used something more realistic, like the same street, but with a different number, or maybe another street which has a similar structure. In any case, I remember that I read StoneyB in his comment once that this kind of thing (home/office addresses) is mostly country-dependent (in English or not), and I agree with him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **the exact method of writing addresses depends very much on local custom**.  In the US, UK, Canada, and Australia, the normal form is something like this:

```
522 3rd Avenue #4
```

This means

- the street is "3rd Avenue"
- the house number is 522; that is, this is the 522nd building on 3rd Avenue
- the number of the apartment (or *flat*, or unit) within the building is 4.

We don't usually say or write out "number" or "No." for the house number except in a few famous cases like *Number 10 Downing Street* (where the executive branch of the government of the UK is headquartered).

The issue in your case arises because in English-speaking countries we don't usually begin street names with a number!  If the street name itself is a number, like *3rd Street* or *5th Avenue*, we usually write it as an *ordinal*, like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

To answer one of your original questions, **if the street is really named "15 Alpha Street", then no, I would not assume that there are multiple Alpha Streets**.  The US has a few "4th of July" roads and Montevideo, Uruguay has streets like "18 de Julio"; I don't think anybody thinks there is also a "5th of July" road and a "19 de Julio" avenue.

But if the street name itself begins with a number, like "15 Alpha Street", then something like

```
20 15 Alpha Street
```

becomes very confusing, because we're only used to seeing one number before a street name, and that number is the house number.  **If there is only one "15 Alpha Street", then I would write out the address like**

```
No. 21, 15 Alpha St
Babol, Mazandaran
Iran
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the location. However, I'm trying to answer this for what it looks to me *in general*.

If you write 15 Alpha street, it means that there are **many** Alpha streets. The reason is **there is no comma**. So,

> 15 Alpha Street, 14 Alpha Street and so on.

The moment you put a **comma**, things are changed.

> 15, Alpha Street

It may **then** mean that you are talking about a specific shop or house (or whatever) numbered '15'. **But** the Alpha Street is just **one**.

Example:

[image: alpha street example]

Here, we are talking about house/bungalow number 15. There are many bungalows with number 1, 2, .... 15, 16, ... and so on. **But** there's *only* **one** Alpha street. The other streets are with *different name*, say Queen Street here.

But in your example, you add *one more* number - No. 21. Say it is some place -house/shop. In my opinion, now it means that it is a property numbered 21 **and** there are many Alpha Streets. This property is on 15th Alpha Street and not on 2nd or 14th Alpha Street.

---

After additional information:

If 21 is a house number, it goes just like that - 21.
If, 15 Alpha is 'one name', it goes after a comma. A comma is after 21 then. Clarify it telling 'house number' for better understanding.

> House No 21 
>  15 Alpha Street 
>  XYZ -1101