# How to write my address?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I live in Kazakhstan and I have to provide my address for one U.S. site. There are 3 lines : Street Address 1(street address, P.O. Box, c/o), Street Address 2, Street Address 3. How should I fill this lines if I live in Ikhsanov street, house/apartment 105(btw, what do Americans write here house or anything else?), flat/door 17(here's the same thing, what should I write?) for instance.

Thank you.

Comment: I would ask your local post office. It should be the same format that is used on your mail. But this really isn't a language question.

Comment: @user3169 Thank you, it's really important and I have to do this now. Unfortunately, post office doesn't work right now it's too late. If it is not a language question do you know where can I ask this question(I mean may be there is another stack community for this purposes)? I've asked here because another guy asked almost the same one here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76093/how-to-write-our-home-address-in-formal-forms.

Comment: Why not just check how your address is written on some mail you received? When you provide your information overseas, the purpose for this is so they can send you mail/parcels as necessary. Changing the format will only confuse your local post office.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about international postal addressing conventions / standards, not the use of English

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your side question -- In America, we would write it this way:

105 Ikhsanov Street
Apartment 17
Cityname, Statename PostalCode

I really want to say that international postal etiquette expects you to write the address in the format used at the recipient's location, with the country name written in (at least) the sender's language and the recipient's language (Maybe also in French.  Is French still the international postal language? I'm not sure.) but I may be out of date.

In your case, assuming that a US web site only allows two lines plus city-state-zip, I would probably write it as

Ikhsanov Street
House 105, Flat 17

Comment: If I only had two lines for this address, I would write `105 Ikhsanov Street Apt 17` on Line 1, and the I'd write `Cityname, Statename PostalCode` on Line 2.

Comment: Edited to specify the common usage of the phrase "2 address lines"